# How to calculate megabytes?

Tags: bit

I'm doing an exercise. But I'm confused on how to calculate the megabytes

**A “genome” can be represented as a sequence of “bases”, each of which can be encoded as a two-bit value. Assuming that a megabit is 1,000,000 bits, how many megabytes are required to encode a 16 million base genome?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line about "a megabit is 1,000,000 bits" seems to suggest:

- 8 bits in a byte
- 1,000 bytes in a kilobyte
- 1,000 kilobytes in a megabyte

Therefore:

- 1,000,000 bytes in a megabyte; or
- 8,000,000 bits in a megabyte

Answer (score 1):

16mln * 2 bit / MB = 32 MBit / MB = 32 MB / 8MB = 32 / 8 = **4**

Comment: Thank you for the calculation :)

Answer (score 1):

1 byte = 8 bits. Today, at least.